# How to automatically register new instances from autoscaling group to haproxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am using haproxy for frontend load balancing on AWS. I have two backend servers on autoscaling group. How can i automate the registration of new instances to haproxy. Am using chef for configuration. It would be great if someone provide me the script to automate this process..

Answer (score 1):

Using the app_lb recipe in the haproxy community cookbook should manage this for you automatically through search.

http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/haproxy